# With IdentityServer3 I'm unable to display the loaded user details as per their sample

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver3

I'm following the IdentityServer3 jsGettingStarted sample [github sample](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/jsGettingStarted.html)
But I'm trying to do so using MVC.
(The IdentityServer itself is in a separate project and solution as per the sample documentation.)
Providing the index.html page is via a Controller-Action, which is fine.

The login popup "popup.html" which is actually "popup.cshtml" is also via a Controller action and it also displays, but it won't close and display the user credentials in the index page as shown in the Sample.
But putting a few alerts in, .. the user is definitely logged in.

I also tried moving the popup.html into the root of the project (as .html and not as .cshtml and changing the server's Client.cs' RedirectUris to reflect that change) but without success.

Is it because of the cshtml pages being served from my controller actions ?
The documentation says that this should display by calling the display function, but the "manager.events.addUserLoaded" function is not firing, which calls the display function.

I am using VS2017 MVC5 with Framework 4.8.

Thanks

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/oidc-client.js"></script>

<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JS Application</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled requests">
                <li><a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary">Home</a></li>
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-login">Login</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">User data</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <pre class="js-user"></pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

// helper function to show data to the user
function display(selector, data)
{
    if (data && typeof data === 'string')
    {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    }
    if (data)
    {
        data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    }

    alert("selector=" + data);
    $(selector).text(data);
}
var settings = {
    authority: 'https://localhost:44302',  // The url of the IdentityServer
    client_id: 'js',  
    popup_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:44888/Account/Popup',
    response_type: 'id_token token',  
    scope: 'openid profile email',       
    filterProtocolClaims: true
};

var manager = new Oidc.UserManager(settings);
var user;

manager.events.addUserLoaded(function (loadedUser)
{
    alert("userManager");
    user = loadedUser;
    display('.js-user', user);   
});

$('.js-login').on('click', function ()
{
    manager
        .signinPopup()
        .catch(function (error)
        {
            console.error('error while logging in through the current window or popup', error);
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating a standalone project rather than trying to do it in already established project, I managed to get it to work. There were clashes in the scripts and css we were already using.